# please someone explain me what is this in php?

Tags: php, arrays

everyone. I write this code in my test php. Once I execute in browser, it's just display the initial, the first letter of array. For further, here is my code:

`$args = array ('computer'=>'pentium', 'notebook'=>'atom', 'gadget'=>'tab');` 
`foreach ($args as $key => $val)`
`{echo $key['val'];}`

and the result in my browser is "cng" which I think c = computer, n = notebook, g = gadget.

so, would someone explain me how could it happens?

thanks in advance

Comment: what you probably want is `echo $val`

Answer (score 8):

PHP is evaluating `$key['val']` as `$key[0]` and giving you the first letter of each "key"

In your example, `$key` is not an array, it is a string containing `computer`, `notebook` or `gadget` for the respective iteration through `$args`.  PHP evaluates `'val'` as an integer because you are calling the array key syntax on a string.

From the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr)

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying
>   the ***zero-based offset*** of the desired character after the string using
>   square array brackets, as in $str[42]. Think of a string as an array
>   of characters for this purpose. The functions substr() and
>   substr_replace() can be used when you want to extract or replace more
>   than 1 character.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation. I learn array from this [link]http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php[/link] with the sample of array is:

`$array = array ('foo' => 'bar');`

I think that is array which contains string. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"Foreach" loop iterates through array according to its length. It separates the value and key in array and convert them to string for example in your case when loop iterates once it gives following output.

```
     echo $key; // "computer"
     echo $val; // "pentium"
```

You can get value by using just $val in every iterate. So after every iteration there will be new pair of $key and $value according to the values in the array. Hope you get it.

Comment: so, how to implement if I want to display like this?

product :: detail
computer - pentium
notebook - atom

Comment: You have to just write this line within loop (echo $key." - ".$val;)

Comment: oh God, lost in my head.

Thanks a lot @Zohaib and everyone :)